# How to get width/height of a video stream via gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

How to get width/height of a video stream via gstreamer? I have a pipeline coded in C++ with the following structure:

```
rtspsrc -> rtpjitterbuffer -> rtph264depay -> mpegtsmux -> filesink
```

My task is: When I get a first image data (either h264 encoded or mjpeg) I need to query width and height from it. Is it possible?
I tried to get current caps from 'src' pad of rtph264depay and get width/height from its structure, but failed to do the last.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same task for a RTP H264 stream. Coding in C++.

I'll give a short code snippet for future developers.

My pipe looks like this.

```
auto source = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", nullptr);
auto rtpJitterBuffer = gst_element_factory_make("rtpjitterbuffer", nullptr);
auto depay = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", nullptr);
auto h264parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", nullptr);
auto decode = gst_element_factory_make("openh264dec", nullptr);
auto sinkV = gst_element_factory_make("glimagesink", nullptr);
```

I used a probe pad for my decoder.
Therefore you need a

```
GstPadProbeCallback
```

like

```
static GstPadProbeReturn pad_cb(GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer user_data) {

    GstEvent *event = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_EVENT(info);
    if (GST_EVENT_CAPS == GST_EVENT_TYPE(event)) {
      GstCaps * caps = gst_caps_new_any();
      int width, height;
      gst_event_parse_caps(event, &caps);

      GstStructure *s = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);

      gboolean res;
      res = gst_structure_get_int (s, "width", &width);
      res |= gst_structure_get_int (s, "height", &height);
      if (!res) {
          qWarning() << "no dimenions";
      }
      qDebug() << "GST_EVENT_CAPS" << width << height;
   }
   return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
```

You can than add the probe to your pad like so

```
auto *pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(decode, "src");

gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_BOTH, pad_cb, &customData_, nullptr);
gst_object_unref(pad);
```

This callback will be called everytime the format changes. You don't need to check for both directions, but I did it anyways.

Comment: This solution needs to decode stream and increase CPU usage.

Comment: I think you got a memory leak there. Shouldn't that line be `GstCaps * caps = NULL;`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the typefind element which is used to find the media type of a stream and get the caps from it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 0.10? It is old and obsolete and unmantained for years. Please move to 1.0.

That said, in 0.10 you can register a callback for the notify:caps signal in an element's pad. So you can do that in the h264depay and check if it has the width/height fields. If it does not, you can add an h264parse and that should likely find out width and height for you and you can use the notify:caps in its source pad.

In 1.0 it should work the same, but use an event probe on the pad and look for the CAPS event.